# fail to install ffi in macosx14.0

Tags: macos, ffi

install command:
`sudo gem install ffi`

error msg:

```
ld: warning: -multiply_defined is obsolete
ld: warning: search path '/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/98ed8ad3-3356-11ee-9b53-aead88ae2785/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.Internal.sdk/usr/local/lib' not found
ld: archive member '/' not a mach-o file in '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/ext/ffi_c/libffi-universal-darwin23/.libs/libffi_convenience.a'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ffi_c.bundle] Error 1
```

env:

```
Ruby: 2.6.0
MacOS: 14.0
Xcode: 15.0.1
```

Maybe the ffi not adapt MacOSX14.0?

Answer (score 0):

```
brew reinstall libffi
```

This helped me to solve this issue.
More info: https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/651